# function which takes a string input and removes all the characters which occur a certain number of times

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, function, dictionary

I have a word "angoora" here 'a' and 'o' occurs 2 time if user input is 2 then output should be "ngr" function should remove a and o because it occur 2 times in a string. if user enter 3 then output should be "angoora" because no character occur 3 times.

I am doing this but I think its not a right way because its not leading me towards my goal, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
public static SortedDictionary<char, int> Count(string stringToCount)
{
    SortedDictionary<char, int> characterCount = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();

    foreach (var character in stringToCount)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        characterCount.TryGetValue(character, out counter);
        characterCount[character] = counter + 1;
    }

    return characterCount;
}
```

Comment: "not leading me towards my goal" What does that mean exactly? Do you get what you expect or do you get an error or unexpected result?

Comment: `stringToCount.Where(z => characterCount[z] < desiredNumber)` may get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can use this Function

```
static string Fix(string item, int count)
{
    var chars = item.ToList().GroupBy(g => g).Select(s => new { Ch = s.Key.ToString(), Count = s.Count() }).Where(w => w.Count < count).ToList();
    var characters = string.Join("", item.ToList().Select(s => s.ToString()).Where(wi => chars.Any(a => a.Ch == wi)).ToList());
    return characters;
}
```

Comment: well finally I have got my solution

Comment: `item.ToList()` should just be `item`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQs GroupBy to find the number of times each character occurs. Then remove the ones that occur the number of times you want. Something like this

```
public static string RemoveCharactersThatOccurNumberOfTimes(string s, int numberOfOccurances)
{
    var charactersToBeRemoved = s.GroupBy(c => c).Where(g => g.Count() == numberOfOccurances).Select(g => g.Key);
    return String.Join("", s.Where(c => !charactersToBeRemoved.Contains(c)));
}
```

Comment: your solution is better but if you wrap those code in function then i think he accept your solution because he need function :)

Comment: @ershoaib Good suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `characterCount` SortedDictionary is empty.

Currently you are doing:

```
public static SortedDictionary<char, int> Count(string stringToCount)
{
    // Create a new empty SortedDictionary
     SortedDictionary<char, int> characterCount = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();

    // Loop through each character in stringToCount and see if SortedDictionary contains a key equal to this character (it doesn't as dictionary is empty).
    foreach (var character in stringToCount)
     {
         int counter = 0;
         characterCount.TryGetValue(character, out counter);
         characterCount[character] = counter +1;
     }

     return characterCount;
}
```

Surely you want something like this:

```
public static SortedDictionary<char, int> Count(string stringToCount)
{
    // Create a new empty SortedDictionary (use var keyword if defining variables)
    var characterCount = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();

    // Loop through each character and add to dictionary
    foreach (var character in stringToCount)
    {
        // If character already in SortedDictionary.
        if (characterCount.TryGetValue(character, out int count))
        {
            // Increment count value.
            characterCount[character] = count + 1;
            // Above line can also be: ++characterCount[character];
        }
        // Else, character not already in dictionary.
        else
        {
            // Add character in dictionary and set count to 1.
            characterCount.Add(character, 1);
        }
    }

    return characterCount;
}
```

Comment: Edited after mjwills suggestion about using TryGetValue instead of ContainsKey

Comment: How is that different to the original code? It looks basically the same to me.

Comment: `// Above line can also be: ++characterCount[character];` Don't do that, or you get another hash lookup.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string foobar(string given, int number)
{
    string result = given;
    foreach (char c in result.Distinct())
    {
        if (given.Count(ch => c == ch) >= number) result= result.Replace(c.ToString(),"");
    }
    return result;
}
```

`Distinct()` will give you only unique characters.
Then you `Count()` the occurance of each unique character and remove if it is greater or equal the given number.

Comment: Since you're not passing `given` using `ref` your modification of it is lost when the function returns. In general I'm not a big fan of modifying parameters. I'd have the function return the new string.

Comment: @HansKilian I wanted to show just how it could work, but you're right. I updated it.